# EndDialogAsync Issue Botframework V4

Tags: botframework

I have a parent dialog that calls a child one.
Code snippet as follows.

```
    public Activity2MainDialog(UserState userState, string dialogMainId)
                    : base(dialogMainId)
            {
                InitialDialogId = Id;
                _studentProfileAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<StudentProfile>("studentProfile");

                WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
                {
                    ActHardwareSetupStepAsync,
                    MsgWelcomeStepAsync,
                    QuestGoAheadStepAsync,
                    ReplyGoAheadStepAsync,
                    QuestWhatIsALedLedStepAsync,
                    ReplyWhatIsALedLedStepAsync,
                    QuestAcceptChallengeStepAsync,
                    ReplyAcceptChallengeStepAsync                    
                };

                // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
                AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(dialogMainId, waterfallSteps));
                AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
                AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
                AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
            }
            private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActHardwareSetupStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {            
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync("environmentSetupDialog", "activity2MainDialog", cancellationToken);         
            }
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MsgWelcomeStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            conversationSessionID = stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id;
            conversationFromUser = stepContext.Context.Activity.Recipient.Name;
            var studentProfile = await _studentProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new StudentProfile(), cancellationToken);
            if (studentProfile.Name == null)
            {
                studentProfile.Name = "Usuario de Teste";
            }
            message = $"Oiii **{studentProfile.Name}!**";
            speakMessage = $"Oiii {studentProfile.Name}!";
            await SendMessage(message, BellaMain.SSMLWrap(speakMessage, "robot"), stepContext, cancellationToken);
            BellaMain.BotWait(message.Length.ToString());
            message = "Eu sou o Planck e estou aqui para ensinar a você um pouco mais sobre assuntos, digamos, habilidosos. ";
            speakMessage = "Eu sou o Planck e estou aqui para ensinar a você um pouco mais sobre assuntos, digamos, habilidosos.";
            await SendMessage(message, BellaMain.SSMLWrap(speakMessage, "robot"), stepContext, cancellationToken);
            BellaMain.BotWait(message.Length.ToString());
            message = "Eu adoro construir robôs, drones e outras invenções tecnológicas. Espero que você também goste!";
            await SendMessage(message, BellaMain.SSMLWrap(message, "robot"), stepContext, cancellationToken);
            BellaMain.BotWait(message.Length.ToString());         
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
```

The child dialog executes well, finishes and then returns the dialog flow to the parent.
Child dialog code snippet below.

```
public class EnvironmentSetupDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private static BellaMain BellaMain = new BellaMain();        

        private static string message;
        private static string speakMessage;
        private static string invalidValueMessage;
        private static string conversationSessionID = "";
        private static string conversationFromUser = "";

        public EnvironmentSetupDialog(UserState userState, string dialogMainId)
                : base(dialogMainId)
        {
            InitialDialogId = Id;

            WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                QuestStartupWordStepAsync,
                ReplyStartupWordStepAsync
            };

            // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(dialogMainId, waterfallSteps));            
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt("startupWord", NamePromptValidatorAsync));                        
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> QuestStartupWordStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            message = "**CONFIGURAÇÃO DE AMBIENTE**";
            speakMessage = "CONFIGURAÇÃO DE AMBIENTE";
            await SendMessage(message, BellaMain.SSMLWrap(speakMessage, "robot"), stepContext, cancellationToken);

            //Changing message depending on calling dialog
            var callerActivityDialog = stepContext.Options.ToString().ToLower();
            switch (callerActivityDialog)
            {
                case "activity2maindialog":
                    message = "Clique no botão do microfone e fale a palavra mágica de hoje que é... XXX";
                    speakMessage = "Clique no botão do microfone e fale a palavra mágica de hoje que é... XXX";
                    break;
                case "activity3maindialog":
                    message = "Hoje a palavra mágica é... YYY";
                    speakMessage = "Hoje a palavra mágica é... YYY";
                    break;
            }
            LogMessage(message, stepContext, cancellationToken);
            invalidValueMessage = "A palavra mágica deve conter pelo menos 3 caracteres. Poderia falar novamente, por favor?";
            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(message,BellaMain.SSMLWrap(speakMessage, "robot")),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text(invalidValueMessage, BellaMain.SSMLWrap(invalidValueMessage, "robot")),
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("startupWord", promptOptions, cancellationToken);

        }
        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ReplyStartupWordStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            stepContext.Values["startupWord"] = (string)stepContext.Result;
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
```

BotWait Code:

```
public async Task<String> BotWait(string timespan)
        {
            var seconds = 0;
            double n;
            Task taskA = null;
            //Generates a time span based on the number of character of a given message
            if (double.TryParse(timespan, out n))
            {
                var timeRatio = 10;
                if (BellaMain.GlobalVariable.SpeedStyle == "normal")
                {
                    seconds = Convert.ToInt32(timespan) / timeRatio;
                }
                else //SpeedStyle == "fast"
                {
                    seconds = 1;
                }
            }
            //Generates a time span based on informed parameters
            else
            {
                if (BellaMain.GlobalVariable.SpeedStyle == "normal")
                {
                    switch (timespan)
                    {
                        case "bit":
                            seconds = 2;
                            break;
                        case "while":
                            seconds = 5;
                            break;
                        case "byte":
                            seconds = 7;
                            break;
                        case "brief":
                            seconds = 10;
                            break;
                        case "briefier":
                            seconds = 12;
                            break;
                        case "midbrief":
                            seconds = 15;
                            break;
                        case "midlongbrief":
                            seconds = 20;
                            break;
                        case "longbrief":
                            seconds = 25;
                            break;
                        case "long":
                            seconds = 40;
                            break;
                        case "longer":
                            seconds = 60;
                            break;
                        case "extralong":
                            seconds = 90;
                            break;
                        case "image":
                            seconds = 7;
                            break;
                        case "gif":
                            seconds = 10;
                            break;
                        case "carousel":
                            seconds = 50;
                            break;
                        case "video":
                            seconds = 60;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (timespan)
                    {
                        case "bit":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "while":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "byte":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "brief":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "briefier":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "midbrief":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "midlongbrief":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "longbrief":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "long":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "longer":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "extralong":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "image":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "gif":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "carousel":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                        case "video":
                            seconds = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            taskA = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000));
            taskA.Wait();
            return null;
        }
```

The issue: a few seconds later a 'Couldn't Send Retry' message is triggered.
I believe it has to do with the way I'm calling/ending the child dialog.
Thoughts on how to fix that?
Thx

Comment: Your methods seem fine to me. Which channel are you access the bot from? Can you check the channel in Azure and see what message it is giving you for the failure?

Comment: What are the next steps in the parent dialog? Is "Couldn't Send Retry" appearing in the client? That would usually indicate the bot is too busy to respond and your code is stuck in an endless loop or has thrown an exception.

Comment: @billoverton
Thx.
I'm using direct line with webchat.js V4.
The error messages remains the same on Azure as in https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httIpDjF44PhleXhtUHQ?e=JdCewk
The triggered error message is `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout`
It doesn't happen on the emulator though.
I was just wondering if there is a way to increase the default timeout value.
Would that be possible?

Comment: @mdrichardson
Thx.
Next steps in the parent dialog added in the problem statement.
I believe the issue is happening due to a `BotWait` method call.
It pauses the execution for an "x" amount of milesecs depending on the text size.
We need it to sync the bot displayed text to the spoken voice.
I was just wondering if there is a way to increase the default timeout time to avoid the error message.
Would that be possible? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Ah, yes I believe that BotWait would cause it. I also run into issues like this on long running integration calls. The bot proceeds as normal, but before the response comes the error message is appearing in UI which can confuse the user and - if they type before the step completes - it actually causes the whole step to repeat in my experience. In my case I am planning on trying proactive messages to fix this. But I think that doesn't work for you since the dialog is continuing. I would also be interested in a method to increase the default timeout.

Comment: @billoverton spot on Bill. That's definitively challenging in terms of UI since the timeout message keeps showing up. Hope mdrichardson can shed some light into that. Thx

Comment: Proactive messages are meant for exactly this kind of thing. There's no changing the timeout as that's set at the Bot Framework service level. So, start your `BotWait` asynchronously so that the bot can respond before `BotWait` finishes, then send a proactive message once `BotWait` is done. And yes, the dialog wouldn't work well. End the dialog with `BotWait` and continue it via a new dialog after the proactive message...this part can be tricky.

Comment: @mdrichardson Thanks for the guidance.On the `BotWait` async recommendation I'm not sure if it would work that way. When I try to make it async I get the following message https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httIpFjo1MQYpZKC-gKg from VS. I believe it has to do with this part of the code that apparently doesn't accept await calls:`Task taskA = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000));  taskA.Wait();` Full Botwait code in the problem statement now. Thoughts?

Comment: @mdrichardson Just learnt that Task.Delay(x) accepts async calls. However, the problem remains. One thing that I noticed is that is the behavior for  the errors follows this path: 1) OK - a user action is requested e.g. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httIpHrtR80i97BlGVVg?e=97cYC1  2) Fail - After the action is done. The dialog flow goes on but the data entry keeps hanging and later triggers a `retry` message e.g. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httIpGBWw8RN5zjTQlYQ?e=sqfhU8 I was wondering if there is a way to flush or clear the conversation sending buffer right after the user input...

Comment: I mean asynchronous in the general sense, not with `async` and `await`. You need the code to continue without it being blocked or waiting for it. So call `BotWait` without using `await`. When `BotWait` finishes, have it send a proactive message.

Comment: @mdrichardson Thx.Will be working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call BotWait without using await. When BotWait finishes, have it send a proactive message.